# NHibernate: insert object to collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

I have 2 classes in my NHibernate project: OrderModel and OrderProductModel:

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public OrderModel() { productList = new HashedSet<OrderProductModel>();}
        (...)
        public virtual ISet<OrderProductModel> productList { get; set; }
    }


public class OrderProductModel
    {
        (...)
        public virtual OrderModel orderM { get; set; }
    }
```

I mapping it this way:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Shop.Domain.Model.Order" assembly="Shop.Domain">
  <class name="OrderModel">
    <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <set name="productList" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" table="OrderProductModel" >
      <key column="orderM"/>
      <one-to-many class="OrderProductModel"/>
    </set>
    (...)
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Shop.Domain.Model.Order" assembly="Shop.Domain">
  <class name="OrderProductModel">
    <many-to-one name="orderM" class="OrderModel" column="orderM"/>
    (...)
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to insert order to database by something like this:

```
var p1= new OrderProductModel{...};
var p2= new OrderProductModel{...};
var order = new OrderModel{...};
p1.orderM = order;
p2.orderM = order;
order.productList = new HashedSet<OrderProductModel>{p1, p2} // from Iesi
session.Insert(order) // session is IStatelessSession and it must be
```

It insert order to datebase, but table OrderProductModel is still empty. I realy don't want insert orderProduct manually, I expect NHibernate can to this for me, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Because we used **`inverse="true"`** we must set both sides of relation

```
var p1= new OrderProductModel{...};
var p2= new OrderProductModel{...};
var order = new OrderModel{...};

// new lines
// these are essential part to make inverse mapping to happen
p1.orderM = order;
p2.orderM = order;

order.productList = new HashedSet<OrderProductModel>{p1, p2} // from Iesi
```

What is all about? Why to do that?

Because with setting inverse="true" we say: NHibernate - when you handle collection items - let it on these items. They will take care about save/udpate. So they must know about relationship

That all will work with standard session if we will call

```
session.Save(order);
session.Flush();
```

In case, that we would like to use stateless session, we should know:

[13.2. The StatelessSession interface](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#batch-statelesssession)

> Alternatively, NHibernate provides a command-oriented API that may be used for streaming data to and from the database in the form of detached objects. A IStatelessSession has no persistence context associated with it and does not provide many of the higher-level life cycle semantics. In particular, a stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level or query cache. It does not implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking. **Operations performed using a stateless session do not ever cascade to associated instances.**

So there is no way to profit from the fact that we do have cascading in place

The way to go is:

```
session.Save(order);
session.Save(p1);
session.Save(p2);
```

Comment: I added these lines, but it doesn't help :(

Comment: I added few more lines with more explanations. You should try to avoid stateless session at all.